# Managing memory for long running IO bound process

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a method that runs on a record that involves third party API calls so it's not CPU bound and runs slowly in the background but because the data set is so large it is causing me memory issues.  I cannot load the entire list in one go (it causes exception) so I am paging through it in batches.  This works but each batch is adding to the ram usage as I am assuming it is being tracked by the context.

I think to fix this I could detach each batch after its finished processing.  I tried this:

```
using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
{
    int count = 0;

    while(count < total)
    {
        var toCheck = db.Companies
            .Include(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords)
            .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == false)
            .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
            .Skip(count)
            .Take(1000)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var company in toCheck)
        {
            // do all the stuff that needs to be done
            // removed for brevity but it makes API calls
            // and creates/updates records

            company.CheckedCompaniesHouse = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            count++;
        }
        // attemmpted to detach to free up ram but doesn't work
        db.Entry(toCheck).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

It causes this exception after batch is complete:

> The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current
>   context

I guess this is because I enumerated it to a list and it's actually tracking the records inside the list.

What is the proper way to detach the records and nested records so the ram doesn't fill up?  Should I be approaching this in a different way?

edit:

I also tried detaching each company record as I loop over it but the ram still goes up

```
        foreach (var company in toCheck)
        {
            // do all the stuff that needs to be done
            // removed for brevity but it makes API calls
            // and creates/updates records

            company.CheckedCompaniesHouse = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            count++;
            foreach(var chr in company.CompaniesHouseRecords.ToList())
            {
                db.Entry(chr).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }
            db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
```

Comment: `PlaceDBContext` is where the tracking of the entity is stored, but I'm not sure at what time it clears out cache. There's a few different ways this could be dealt with. An easy though dirty way would be to move `using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())` inside of `while(count < total)` so that the `PlaceDBContext` is recreated for each record set. Depending on how often this happens, this may or may not be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contexts are meant to be short lived and cheap to create, if you're worried that it's hogging memory and that's an issue because your while is long running maybe you could try this :

```
int count = 0;

while(count < total)
{
    using (var db = new PlaceDBContext()) // create a new context each time
    {
        var toCheck = db.Companies
            .Include(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords)
            .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == false)
            .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
            .Skip(count)
            .Take(1000)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var company in toCheck)
        {
            // do all the stuff that needs to be done
            // removed for brevity but it makes API calls
            // and creates/updates records

            company.CheckedCompaniesHouse = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this and the memory still goes up each batch

Comment: i did a longer running test and GC seems to be handling this much better over a long time it was just increasing on the shorter test I did.

Comment: Actually it does stil fill up.  Left it running overnight and after 5,000 records it had timedout and VS was at it ram limit

Comment: @Guerrilla What makes you think it's the context tracking that's filling it up? Any reason why you're processing this one by one (saving on each row change instead of having the save outside the foreach)? Did you use a memory profiler to see how memory looked like when it was filled up and which object it was made of? It has to be something outside of the (i assume simplified) code you posted because there Nothing is helt between each iteration of the while, you should post the "do all the stuff that needs to be done", i'm willing to bet the issue is there

Comment: I marked this as answer but I discovered it is a memory leak in VS2015 that a lot of people are complaining about https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1610160/microsoft-vshub-server-httphostx64-exe

Comment: @Guerrilla Sounds to me like it's not your process at all taking up the ram then but the external VS process, why not launch it without debugging? You won't see this issue in production it's a VS issue not an issue with the compiled exe and running this in debug mode will only make it slower and more memory hungry.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have done and it is running fine.  I hadn't noticed that leaving it running in debugging made like 11gb of ram fill up.  I am not getting issues when running release.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the load, in `var toCheck = ...` use `.AsNoTracking()`

In your `foreach` loop, save the IDs of each row, then use a second db context to load those Companies, except without the Include() that pulls in lots of extra linked objects.

Then do the update on those in the loop, but issue only a single db.SaveChanges() *after* the loop, otherwise you'll make a db roundtrip for each row, which is 1000 at a time

```
using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
{
    int count = 0;

    while(count < total)
    {
        var toCheck = db.Companies
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords)
            .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == false)
            .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
            .Skip(count)
            .Take(1000)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var company in toCheck)
        {
            int tempID = company.ID   // Use whatever field is the id
            // do all the stuff that needs to be done
            // removed for brevity but it makes API calls
            // and creates/updates records

            var companyUpdate = db2.Companies.Where(c => c.ID == tempid).FirstOrDefault();    

            companyUpdate.CheckedCompaniesHouse = true;
            count++;
        }
        db2.SaveChanges();  
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Memory still goes up even if I create the company record from ID.